# How to handle Client Side certicates in angular 9 with .net webapi

Tags: angular, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-2.0, angular9

In one of the requirements, needs to handle client-side certificates in angular. Is there any way to send a certificates bytes array in http request to validate the webapi . validated in webapi , it issues the token.
if not how to handle it angular  once
I have referred this link : but it will only shows the certicated in angular side.

I am not clear about the concept :

How thw webapi will understand the certicate of client side :
https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a

Comment: So, basically you have angular app running over SSL and where is the problem? Can you please provide more explanation

Comment: @ajay Gandhi, is there any possibility to send browser certificates key as a byte array to validate in web API to provide an access token in web API. i have confusion in the concept.if I am a client installed certificate , how the webapi will validate and provide access token.i have not understood the  mechnasim clearly

Comment: I am not sure about Angular. But in general, If you enable the SSL in a site, then you need to send HTTPS request to it. and not the HTTP. In HTTPS, you can pass in the cert to the server. When the client makes HTTPS connection with the server, there are some callback method which get called in server side framework where you can validate the cert supplied by client. If the cert fails, just return false and connection wont be established between client and the server

Comment: yes, that's correct..like that it will work in Auth0, oidc angular client. in my case client have certificate, installed in the machine,if webapi will validate the certificate and issue the access token.Here how angular and webapi sync with certificates how it identies thats my question.